# Node.js express download from mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to write a rest api, with which i am able to download some data. All datas were stored in a mongodb. I don't know what to pass to the `download` method, to make it possible.

Here is my current code:

```
router.get('/download/:productId/:username/:token', function (req, res) {

    var auth = require('../provider/authProvider.js');
    var authInst = new auth();

    authInst.checkAuth(req.params.username, req.params.token, res, function (err, obj) {
        if (obj == true) {
            res.status(200);
            // here is my problem, what to pass to the download-method
            res.download('');
        }
    });        
});
```

I could not find anything else, than passing paths to the `download` method.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Why `download`, that is for downloading static files. Use send, `res.send(obj)` or `res.json(obj)`

Comment: @Jordonias Behause with `download` nodejs use http streaming. Or am i wrong?

Comment: **Download** terms is a bit confusing. What i understand is you want to do CRUD operations with MongoDB, m i right?

Comment: @NarendraSoni You are right and everything works as expected, beside the download operatiom.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to set up mongoose environment, putting config, connecting to MongoDB. If not please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026619/where-do-i-put-database-connection-information-in-a-node-js-app/27032577#27032577).

Now let's say we have a Document in MongoDB as Blog.
So we need to create a model for Blog so that we can do CRUD operations using Mongoose ORM.

you need mongoose module for this to be included in your project.

so run this command from your project root directory, it will automatically download mongoose  for you.
**npm install mongoose --save**

**BlogModel.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var BlogSchema = new Schema({
    "title"   : { type: String },
    "user_id" : { type: String },
    "blog_uri" :{ type: String },
    "post_date" : { type : Date, default: Date.now},
    "body" : { type: String, default: '' },
    "comments" : [
                    { 'content'  : { type: String },
                      'user_id'  : { type: String },
                      'comment_date'     : { type: Date },
                      'votes'    : [
                                    {
                                    'user_id' : { type: String }
                                    }
                                   ] 
                    }
                ],
    "hidden" : {type:Boolean, default: false }
});

mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema);
```

So let's create a separate file called **BlogController.js** where we will write methods for CRUD.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog');
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
exports.create = function(req,res){
    var blog = new Blog(req.body);

    blog.save(function(err){
        if(err)
            res.json({message: "Error occured while saving"});
        else{
            res.redirect('/home');
        }    
    });
};

exports.getAll = function(req,res){
    Blog.find(function(err,blogs){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.json(blogs);
        }
    });
};


exports.get = function(req,res){
    var id ;
    try{
        id = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
        Blog.findById(id,function(err,blog){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.render('blog.ejs', {
                    blog: blog
               });
          }
        });
    }catch(e){
        res.send(404);
    }
};


exports.update = function(req,res){
    var id ;
    try{
        id = new ObjectId(req.params.blog_id);
        Blog.findById(id,function(err,blog){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }

            blog.save(function(err){
                if(err)
                    res.send(err);
                 res.render('blog.ejs', {
                    message: "Blog Updated successfully"
                });
            });
        });
    }catch(e){
        res.send(404);
    }
};

exports.delete = function(req,res){
    var id ;
    try{
        id = new ObjectId(req.params.blog_id);
        Blog.remove({_id:id},function(err,blog){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }
               res.render('blog.ejs', {
                    message: "Blog deleted successfully"
                });
        });
    }catch(e){
        res.send(404);
    } 
};
```

So this was about CRUD using Mongoose. I usually don't use res.render(..) in my projects because i put Templating logic in front end. I just use res.json(..) and pass the json data to the the frontend. So please go ahead and try. I hope i answered your question. You can refer to 
[this](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-todo-app) repo, for better example. [Here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-todo-app/blob/master/app/meetup/controllers/MeetupController.js) i got a very clean CRUD implementation.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your explanation. I have a full running Node.js server with mongoose and every thing (it is working very nice), so i know about that, thank you :) My question was about the `download` method, because i was confused, that only file paths are allowed as a parameter.

Comment: If you didn't noticed, i asked you in my previous comment, whether you are looking for CRUD operations. :) You said yes, so i went ahead writing this answer for you. When you are responding to comments or posting questions. I request you to please make it clear so that everyone can understand. Otherwise confusions can happen. It's okay. You can edit your question and please provide more details, describing what you actually want. It is not at all clear.